# Query column qualifiers corresponding to particular column family and rowkey in particular Hbase table

Tags: hbase

I am very new to Hbase, so it might be possible that my question doesn't make sense.
I want to know the name of all the column qualifiers corresponding to particular Column-Family, rowKey, Table-Name, so that i can iterate through all the column qualifier to extract the data from the table. Is it possible to do this ? if yes, how to do it ? Is there any better way to extract data from the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation here for Result Class https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html
You can use one of following API's as per your requirement.

```
getFamilyMap()
getMap()
getNoVersionMap()
```

Hope this helps.